# aws iot: how to trigger an act rule / lambda only when the message has a different payload than before?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, mqtt, iot

I'm having a lot of inbound messages via mqtt on aws iot. Most of the messages have the same payload, and only change the timestamp.

I need to run a lambda function that stores the data, but I only want to store data points when actually something changed. How can check for this inside the lambda function? Does the lambda function configured under `act`, triggered by `$aws/things/THING-NAME/shadow/update/documents`  runs before the shadow gets updated or after?

this is the configuration of my rule:
[image]

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lambda gets triggered *after* the device shadow has updated.

But importantly the event payload sent to this lambda will contain two keys `{ previous, current }`. The `previous` and `current` keys will contain the full device shadow before and after the update respectively.

So to achieve what you want, you can then compare the `previous` and `current` to see what values have changed, excluding things like timestamps, etc.